# Best 2D interpolation for a set of points (x/y)

Tags: interpolation, plane-geometry

> Given a set of X/Y points in a bounded area  ( `0<=X<=Xmax` and `0<=Y<=Ymax` ), what are the best 'interpolation' methods/algorithms to compute any other point of that plane?

I do have an arbitrary set of pixels I(x,y) in an image (simple grey-value pixels) and would like to interpolate the whole image, i.e. all other points P(x,y) in that image which are not yet of defined value.

What are reliable mathmatical algorithms to do so?

Comment: The easiest approximation is constant approximation. If not, you can try linear interpolation, lagrange or chebyshew polynomials.

Comment: @corbah: I think the 'practical' problem I have is to find which points to use in an interpolation if my set of points is 'arbitrary'. I don't know what good "image processing standard" technqiues would be in such a scenario.

Comment: But even if they are arbitrary you have $x_0<x_1<...<x_{N-1}$, and $y_0<y_1<...<y_{N-1}$ right?

Comment: If you are familiar with convolution you could try normalized convolution. This is especially useful if the "known" data points are spread arbitrarily over the image.

Comment: @mathreadler Interesting. Do you have some place to read-up on this (other than just googling 'normalized convolution') ? I'm most intersted in a *practical* solution.

Comment: There should be plenty of googlable sources including post graduate theses of various kinds describing it. It can be described as a weighted convolution where a *certainty map* or *certainty image* weighs together the different parts of the convolution. What do you mean by *practical*, should it be possible to get fast enough? Using which softwares or hardwares? Easy to understand?

Comment: http://www2.cvl.isy.liu.se/Research/Filter/normconv.html - probably the most easily accessible explanation together with some examples and links to works which describe and include it.

Comment: @mathreadler I gave it a go now, and it seems exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.